# All activity logging

Tags: php, mysql, logging

I'm creating a PHP-MySQL application for an insurance business that contains information of the insurances, accidents.
The application is not started yet but I need to log ALL THE ACTIVITIES one user does in the page, ALL of them, that means if the user modify an textfile, the DB save the date, hour, file and line the user modified.

I know how to do the base application, but im really confused in that activity log.
Can you help me on it? I need to assign a variable to all the fields or something?

All the help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what have you done so far ??

Comment: I haven't started it yet. Until I haven't know how to solve this term cause is the base of the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're going to store log data in database, and you're using some MVC, you can simply override every controller base class like this:

```
class DefaultController extends LogController
{
    public function update($objectId)
    {
        // do stuff like check POST values and update query

        $this->log('Object with ID: '.$objectId.' has been updated successfuly', 1);
    }

    public function delete($objectId)
    {
        // mysql query to delete the object

        $this->log('Object with ID: '.$objectId.' has been removed!', 1);
    }
}
```

and the LogController:

```
abstract class LogController extends BaseController // if you use any, just like Symfony does
{
    public function log($message, $status)
    {
        $user = $_SESSION['userId']; // I assume you keep online user info somewhere

        // get connection to a database and...
        $connection->query('INSERT INTO logs (message, user_id, status) VALUES ("'.$message.'", '.$user.', '.$status.')');
    }
}
```

But if you're not using MVC structure or any other object oriented template, then do simple log function like this:

```
function logAction($message, $status, $connection)
{
    $user = $_SESSION['userId'];
    $connection->query(/* insert query */);
}
```

The reason why I suggest you to pass the $connection to database is to not open new connections if you just used one. You can always do a simple check in `logAction()` function, if connection has been established and create new one if has not.

**EDIT:**

Ah, forgot.. Here you have MySQL query to create log table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a `log` table in your database. For every action you do in the system you then insert a record into the `log` table with a reference to the activity, a timestamp and the username.

Comment: That means I must stack an id number to all the files and create a table that contains when the id has been changed?

Comment: I would never have files in a database without ID's so probably yes. You could link them by filename, but that sounds dangerous.

Comment: So, does exist  a function for save in a log the activities depending of an id number?

Comment: If it's bare SQL and PHP then you'll have to code it yourself I guess.